# Setting ItemsSource of derived ListBox throws "Catastrophic failure"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing for Windows 8 WinRT framework. The following sample code throws an exception:

`Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`

Is this one more bug in the current WinRT framework (I'm using VS11 and Consumer Preview)? Has someone an idea how to solve this problem?

Btw: I have tested the same code with Windows Phone 7.5 Silverlight and it works without problems...

Thanks for your help.

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{

}

public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
{
    public BlankPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var box1 = new ListBox(); 
        box1.ItemsSource = new List<Object> { new Object() }; // works without problems
        Content = box1; 

        var box2 = new MyListBox();
        box2.ItemsSource = new List<Object> { new Object() }; // throws exception
        Content = box2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is [a known bug in the Windows 8 Consumer Preview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/295d7ee6-8bc4-4326-9ea7-b68ee4c98a7a).

Comment: Ah, COM error reporting is back!

Comment: did you find any workarounds?

Comment: Nope. Waiting for next release (RC) of Win8, at the moment too many bugs...

Comment: Items.Add() and Items.RemoveAt() work with the current version. Unfortunately, I can't wait for the next release

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when subclassing ListView. In my case the following approach partially helped:
I stopped trying to set ItemsSource of my ListView directly in the code behind but instead I created CollectionViewSource in XAML like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="myCollectionViewSource"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
...
<ListView
    ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollectionViewSource}}" />
```

And in the code behind I set

```
this.myCollectionViewSource.Source = new List<Object> { new Object() }; // The real data source respectively
```

However this seems only to postpone the problem. At least in my case. In my real example I use ObservableVector as the data source. And as soon as any change of ObservableVector collection is performed (for example Clear) I also experience Catastrophic failure (0x8000FFFF). As soon as I use the original ListView (not my subclassed version) all works fine again - exactly as in your case. So my reply cannot be understood as the solution of the problem but maybe it is a hint worth trying. In my case the original assignment works fine, the problems come first after observable collection tries to update. I experimented with ObservableCollection (should work in CP, it did not in DP) but there I faced other problems. It would be interesting to hear whether you was able to make any progress down this road...

Comment: Yes, I also had problems when `PropertyChanged` or `CollectionChanged` events are called... At the moment I stopped worked on my project (or this particular problem) and I am waiting for the RC which should be available in June. I also had a lot of other problems (DateTime/struct type dependency property not working, apps only work in simulator - session crashes otherwise, vs crashing when opening xaml files, Popup class kills bindings in contained controls, ...) I don't have the time to build workarounds for all this... :) Anyway, thanks for your answer. Maybe I will give it a shot

Comment: I understand. It is quite frustrating. I am hesitating myself. However last time I put my hopes to DP->CP switch and it did not magically solve the most burning issues - I still had to build workarounds - only different ones ;)  Hopefully the RC experience really will be much smoother.

Comment: Indeed DP->CP solved many problems (multiple NotifyPropertyChanged /ObservableCollection/Vector mess)...

Comment: I have the same issue, in windows phone 8.1 xaml (winrt). I made a control that inherits from Listview to add load more on end of scrolling, All is working fine except when user presses quickly on the list after he presses refresh button (which clears bounded observableCollection and loads new data).

Also note that when i used the normal list view, it worked fine.

Any Suggestions?